# Exibir dias da semana em ordem com PHP

Tags: php

Tenho esse html:

```
<div class="base-semana">
                <div class="dia-semana">
                    <div class="dial">
                        DIA DA SEMANA
                    </div>
                </div>
</div>
```

As divs com classe "dia-semana" possuem 7 iguais. Gostaria de exibir todos os dias da semana em ordem partindo do atual.

Por ex: na primeira div seria no caso hoje: Terça-Feira, e na última Segunda-Feira. Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Só tem esse HTML? Tem algum PHP?

Comment: Só tem o html, estou querendo fazer o php para exibir o que eu quero, entende? Porém existe 7 divs da classe "dia-semana" dentro da "base-semana" coloquei apenas uma para diminuir o post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**exemplo - ideone**](https://ideone.com/SQtezd)

```
    $output ="";
    $semana = array(

    '1' => 'Segunda-Feira',
    '2' => 'Terca-Feira',
    '3' => 'Quarta-Feira',
    '4' => 'Quinta-Feira',
    '5' => 'Sexta-Feira',
    '6' => 'Sábado',
    '7' => 'Domingo'
);

$a = array_slice($semana, date('w') - 1 );

$b = array_slice($semana, 0 , date('w') - 1 );

$c = array_merge_recursive( $a , $b );

foreach( $c as $key => $value ) {

    $output = $output . '<div class="dia-semana"><div class="dial">'. $value . "</div></div>" ;
}

$result = '<div class="base-semana">'.$output.'</div>' ; 

echo $result;
```

> $a = retorna a sequência de todos os elementos de $semana a partir de [date('w')-1], sendo date('w') a representação numérica do dia da semana.
>
> $b = retorna a sequência dos elementos do array $semana de zero até [date('w')-1], sendo date('w') a representação numérica do dia da semana.
>
> $c = funde os elementos de $a com o array $b de forma que os elementos de $b são colocados no final do array $a.

**Para definir o resultado de acordo com o horário de Brasília ao invés do horário do servidor coloque essa linha  `date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');`  no inicio do PHP.**  [Referência - date_default_timezone_set](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Comment: Já que a sua solução foi aceita, tem como descrever o que acontece ao chamar as funções `array_*` para que o resultado seja o esperado?

Comment: Primeiro a solução, depois a redação.

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = [ 1 => 'seg' , 2 => 'ter' , 3 => 'qua' , 4 => 'qui' , 5 => 'sex' , 6 => 'sab' , 7 => 'dom' ];

$b[] = array_slice($a, date('N') - 1 );
$b[] = array_slice($a, 0 , date('N') - 1 );
$c   = array_merge_recursive( $b[0] , $b[1] );

print_r( $c );
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => ter
    [1] => qua
    [2] => qui
    [3] => sex
    [4] => sab
    [5] => dom
    [6] => seg
)
```

Basta aplicar um loop na variável `$c`.

Comment: Não funcionou, acho que você não entendeu muito bem. É para cada div exibir um dia diferente em ordem.

Comment: Olhe este print e veja como é: http://prnt.sc/f5z7di

Comment: `[...]primeira div seria no caso hoje: Terça-Feira, e na última Segunda-Feira[...]` O output é exatamente o que você disse... inicio na terça e segunda no fim... Explique melhor então seu problema.

Comment: Mostrei como fazer a reordenação dos dias da semana baseando-se no dia atual, **basta aplicar um loop na variável $c** para montar seu html.

Comment: Eu não quero fazer uma array, e sim exibir os dados em ordem contando do dia atual, Terça-Feira foi um exemplo contando de hoje. Verifique o print.

Comment: Mas a partir do *array* você é capaz de exibir o que deseja. Se não está familiarizado com laços de repetição, leia [aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php).